# Makefile executes only the first target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have files that look like this

```
1_0_fa.bam  1_1_fa.bam  1_2_fa.bam  1_3_fa.bam  1_4_fa.bam  1_5_fa.bam
1_6_fa.bam  1_7_fa.bam  1_8_fa.bam  1_9_fa.bam  1_0_mo.bam  1_1_mo.bam
1_2_mo.bam  1_3_mo.bam  1_4_mo.bam  1_5_mo.bam  1_6_mo.bam  1_7_mo.bam
1_8_mo.bam  1_9_mo.bam  1_0_p1.bam  1_1_p1.bam  1_2_p1.bam  1_3_p1.bam
1_4_p1.bam  1_5_p1.bam  1_6_p1.bam  1_7_p1.bam  1_8_p1.bam  1_9_p1.bam
```

I'd like to combine them by bin, which is the second number in the name. Here is my Makefile (GNU make 3.81)

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
bins = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
$(info $(bins))
code = 1

define buildVCF

$(info $(1))
$(eval targ = $(code)_$(1)_bin.vcf)
$(info $(targ))
targs += $(targ)
$(eval deps = $(wildcard $(code)_$(1)_*.bam))
$(info $(deps))

$(targ): $(deps)
    cat $$^ > $$@

endef

$(foreach bin,$(bins),$(eval $(call buildVCF,$(bin))))

all: $(targs)
```

If i do `make -n`, it produces

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0
1_0_bin.vcf
1_0_p1.bam 1_0_mo.bam 1_0_fa.bam
1
1_1_bin.vcf
1_1_fa.bam 1_1_p1.bam 1_1_mo.bam
2
1_2_bin.vcf
1_2_mo.bam 1_2_p1.bam 1_2_fa.bam
3
1_3_bin.vcf
1_3_fa.bam 1_3_mo.bam 1_3_p1.bam
4
1_4_bin.vcf
1_4_mo.bam 1_4_fa.bam 1_4_p1.bam
5
1_5_bin.vcf
1_5_fa.bam 1_5_mo.bam 1_5_p1.bam
6
1_6_bin.vcf
1_6_p1.bam 1_6_fa.bam 1_6_mo.bam
7
1_7_bin.vcf
1_7_fa.bam 1_7_p1.bam 1_7_mo.bam
8
1_8_bin.vcf
1_8_fa.bam 1_8_mo.bam 1_8_p1.bam
9
1_9_bin.vcf
1_9_mo.bam 1_9_p1.bam 1_9_fa.bam
cat 1_0_p1.bam 1_0_mo.bam 1_0_fa.bam > 1_0_bin.vcf
```

Why is not building the rest of the targets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `all` target isn't the first in the Makefile. When you call `make` without a target, the first rule in the Makefile is built, which in this case is the one for `1_0_bin.vcf` (because it is generated first). If you call `make -n all`, it'll work as you expect.

To make it work without an explicit rule, just moving the `all` target to the top won't work because `targs` doesn't have the correct value at that point, but you can make it work using a level of indirection:

```
all: dummy

define buildVCF
...
endef

$(foreach bin,$(bins),$(eval $(call buildVCF,$(bin))))

dummy: $(targs)
```

However, this does seem like a rather roundabout way of doing things. If I were you, I'd attempt to solve the problem with a static pattern rule, such as

```
targs = $(foreach bin,$(bins),$(code)_$(bin)_bin.vcf)

all: $(targs)

$(targs) : $(code)_%_bin.vcf : $(foreach i,fa mo p1,$(code)_%_$(i).bam)
    cat $^ > $@
```

Comment: Or just add the rule `default: all` to the top of the Makefile to explicitly set the default rule.  Simple and clear.

Comment: i like default: all. I'd have to stick with the wildcard as all members of a family (fa, mo, p1) may not be present in each bin.

Answer (score 1):

When no target is specified on the command line make builds the [default goal](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#How-Make-Works).

The default goal is

> the first target (not targets whose names start with ‘.’)

In your makefile the first target is the first target created by the `buildVCF` define.

As Wintermute points out you can't simply move the `all: $(targs)` line above the loop as `targs` doesn't have the correct value yet.

That being said you can either put `all:` above the loop to "reserve" the default target (in which case `all: $(targs)` appends prerequisites to the reserved target) or you can [manually set the default goal](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Variables) with `.DEFAULT_GOAL := all` anywhere in the makefile.

On a different not I haven't fully understood the setup you have but I would imagine you could do this with a simpler set of general pattern (or static pattern) rules.